# Passing Simple Integer to Form1 From Form2

Tags: vb.net

Just trying to figure out how to pass one simple integer(StartingTeam) from Form2 to Form 1.

Form 2 Code

```
Public Class frmTeamChoose
Public StartingTeam As Integer
Public Sub btnTeam1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTeam1.Click
    StartingTeam = 1
End Sub

Public Sub btnTeam2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTeam2.Click
    StartingTeam = 2
End Sub

End Class
```

Form 1 is called Form1

Comment: Forms are classes. How would you pass this integer to a different class?

Answer (score 1):

Although you need to provide more info I 'll try to help you:
I suppose that you have open Form2 from Form1:

```
'In form1:
Dim k as integer=Form2.StartingTeam
```

An improved solution is to create a property:
Form 2 code:

```
 Private miStartingTeam 
 Public Property StartingTeam As Integer
    Get
        Return miStartingTeam 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        miStartingTeam = value
    End Set
 End Property
```

Then your code as it is.
In Form1:

```
'Open Form2
Dim f2 as new Form2
'f2.StartingTeam=1 'if you want to set a value before f2 opening
f2.Show


'Get StartingTeam from f2
dim k as integer=f2.StartingTeam
```

Let me know if you need anything else